# Returning Specific Columns with SUM & COUNT from Collection of Relations

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have Models `Product`, `ProductVariant`, and `Department`

**Department:**

```
id | name | ....
```

**Product:**

```
id | name | sku | department_id | ....
```

**ProductVariant:**

```
id | product_id | quantity | ....
```

And all associated with each other like:

- Relationship `products`: Department `hasMany` Products
- Relationship `department`: Product `belongsTo` Department
- Relationship `variants`: Product `hasMany` ProductVariants
- Relationship `product`: Product `belongsTo` Product

Everything works as expected between relations over Eloquent calls

Now, using Eloquent I'm trying to retrieve a collection of following columns:

```
product.id | product.name | product.variant_count | product.stock | department.name
```

By `product.stock` I mean: `$product->variants->sum('quantity')`, but I'm having hard time getting `SUM` inside `with()` method

What I've tried so far:

```php
      $products = Product::select('id', 'name', 'sku', 'department_id') //gives product.name, sku, etc
            ->withCount('variants')                    //gives product.variants_count
            ->with(['variants' => function($query) {
                $query->select('id', 'product_id', 'quantity'); //gives variants->each.quantity
            }])
            ->with(['department' => function($query) {
                $query->select('id', 'name');              //gives department.name
            }]);
```

This code gives something like this:

```json
[
{
    "id": "2",
    "name": "Letv LU50609 Earphone - Grey",
    "sku": "PT-00002",
    "department_id": "2",
    "variants_count": "1",
    "variants": [
        {
            "id": "2",
            "product_id": "2",
            "quantity": "35"
        }
    ],
    "department": {
        "id": "2",
        "name": "Phones &amp; Tabs Accessories"
    }
},
{
    "id": "3",
    "name": "MI In-Ear Headphones Basic 3.5mm HSEJ03JY",
    "sku": "PT-00003",
    "department_id": "2",
    "variants_count": "5",
    "variants": [
        {
            "id": "3",
            "product_id": "3",
            "quantity": "9"
        },
        {
            "id": "4",
            "product_id": "3",
            "quantity": "9"
        },
        {
            "id": "5",
            "product_id": "3",
            "quantity": "10"
        },
        {
            "id": "6",
            "product_id": "3",
            "quantity": "7"
        },
        {
            "id": "7",
            "product_id": "3",
            "quantity": "7"
        }
    ],
    "department": {
        "id": "2",
        "name": "Phones &amp; Tabs Accessories"
    }
}
]
```

But what I want to achieve is:

```json
[
{
    "id": "2",
    "name": "Letv LU50609 Earphone - Grey",
    "sku": "PT-00002",
    "variants_count": "1",
    "stock": "35",
    "department": "name": "Phones &amp; Tabs Accessories"
},
{
    "id": "3",
    "name": "MI In-Ear Headphones Basic 3.5mm HSEJ03JY",
    "sku": "PT-00003",
    "variants_count": "5",
    "stock": "42",
    "department": "name": "Phones &amp; Tabs Accessories"
}
]
```

How can I achieve this???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Option 1

You could [`map()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/collections#method-map) the collection before return it:

```php
  $products = Product::select('id', 'name', 'sku', 'department_id')
        ->withCount('variants')
        ->with(['variants', 'department'])
        ->get()
        ->map(function ($product){
                return [
                    'id'             => $product->id,
                    'name'           => $product->name,
                    'sku'            => $product->sku,
                    'variants_count' => $product->variants_count,
                    'stock'          => $product->variants->sum('quantity'),
                    'department'     => $product->department->name
                ];
            });
```

## Option 2

Using [API Resources](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-resources). Let me know if you need help in this aspect.

Comment: this map() method is exactly what I'm looking for .. thanks alot .. and yes get() method is required for this to work

Comment: @MuhammadShuja glad to help.

Comment: This solution will load all related models into memory and sum in-memory instead of in-database. Performance-wise, this is no good solution at all. The query builder solutions are actually better.

Answer (score 1):

What about using the query builder something like this:

```php
DB::table('products as product')
   ->select([
        'product.id',
        'product.name',
         DB::raw('count(pv.id) as variant_count'),
         DB::raw('sum(pv.quantity) as stock'),
        'department.name'
   ])
   ->join('department', 'product.department_id', '=', 'department.id')
   ->join('product_variants as pv', 'product.id', '=', 'pv.id')
   ->get();
```

Not sure if this will work exactly like this, but it should give you a path.

Comment: I see, but can't I achieve it by Eloquent only? tried your solution as well but having multiple issues .. may be because am not good with QueryBuilder

Comment: with eloquent will be much more complex I think, it is more readable and close to raw like this. What issues are you facing, can you share?

Answer (score 0):

you can access your required result with this query by checking your database tables

```sql
 SELECT
    products.*,
    SUM(variants.available) AS stock,
    COUNT(variants.id)  as count,
    department.name as department
FROM
    products
LEFT JOIN variants ON products.id = variants.product_id
LEFT JOIN department ON products.department_id= department.id
GROUP BY
    products.id
```

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for can be achieved in many ways. The ideal solution will build the sum within the database for best performance. To achieve so, you can use a custom query together with the Laravel query builder as already explained by @nakov or you use a little exploit of the Eloquent relationship system:

```
$products = Product::query()
    ->join('departments', 'departments.id', '=', 'products.department_id)
    ->withCount('variants as variant_count')
    ->withCount(['variants as stock' => function ($query) {
        $query->selectRaw('SUM(quantity)');  // this may look weird but works
    })
    ->select([
        'products.id',
        'products.name',
        'departments.name as department',
    ])
    ->get();
```